# Can't access data posted from Dialog.ajax to dialog box

Tags: ajax, modal-dialogs, 10

I am opening a simple dialog box from Ajax, using the following code-

```
var exportActionDialog = Dialog.ajax({
  dialog: dialogSettings,
  dialogType: 'modal',
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/web/admin/crm/export-dialog',
  data: { whatever: 'itworking' },
  progress: { type: 'throbber'}
});
exportActionDialog.execute();
```

The dialog actually opens successfully and displays the form associated with the url.

But I can't get the value of the `whatever` post variable.

When I do this

```
Public function buildForm(array $form, FormstateInterface $form_state) {
$whatever = $this->getRequest()->request->get('whatever');

dpm($whatever); // returns null
```

The `$whatever` variable returns as null.

Now the actual reason I want to use a post is because I want to pass an array which can contain up to 1000 elements or more. Doing this using Get makes the url unreasonably long.

Just hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Pls any clues guys?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace the `data` key with `submit`. Drupal.ajax() transfers the submit key to the data key of [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) but ignores a data key already set:

```
var exportActionDialog = Drupal.ajax({
  dialog: dialogSettings,
  dialogType: 'modal',
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  url: '/web/admin/crm/export-dialog',
  submit: { whatever: 'itworking' },
  progress: { type: 'throbber'}
});
exportActionDialog.execute();
```

Similar the legacy jQuery `type` key, now `method`, where Drupal is using `httpMethod`. In this case no problem, POST is default.